# NSWindow deprecated in NSWindowController in OSX Lion

Tags: macos, nswindow, osx-lion, nswindowcontroller

I have a subclass defined as follows,

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ICMusicBrowserWindowController : NSWindowController
{

}
```

I then create an instance of the above subclass as follows

```
ICMusicBrowserWindowController *musicBrowserWindowController = [[ICMusicBrowserWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Browser"];
[musicBrowserWindowController setDelegate:self];
```

I try to ask for `window` from `musicBrowserWindowController` like so.

```
[NSApp beginSheet:[musicBrowserWindowController window] 
   modalForWindow:[[self view] window]
    modalDelegate:self 
   didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
      contextInfo:nil];
```

However when doing so, I get the warning message, `window maybe deprecated because receiver type is unknown`.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? I noticed this warning message only appeared in OSX Lion. Thanks.

Comment: In your code that shows the sheet, what is `self` and what is the return type of `[self view]`?

Comment: `self` refers to the view controller and `[self view]` is asking the view controller for it's view.

Comment: Odd. There is a method called `-window` that was deprecated in Mac OS X v10.6 but you should only get a warning if you’re trying to send `-window` to a generic type like `id` (which is related to the message ‘receiver type is unknown’. Since `-[NSViewController view]` returns `NSView *`, the compiler should know that `-[NSView window]` isn’t the method that’s been deprecated.

Comment: Is your view controller a subclass of `NSViewController`? If not, what is the return type of `-view` as declared in the corresponding header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:  i just put the header of my subClass of NSWindowController into the class where i was using the [instance window]
and the warning went away...  (i had also put in forward declaration @Class of my subclass of NSWindowController into the header of where i was using it)  one or both of these fixed the warning...  so try that.

so my previous answer was off i now believe.